# Simpler way to remove repeated header rows in R data table

Tags: r, dplyr, row

I have a `df`that has repeated header rows every 12 rows, a legacy of scraping MLB pitching stats on ESPN's website. I know I can simply remove them like so:

```
12  RK  PLAYER  TEAM GP GS IP H R ER BB SO W L  SV  BLSV WAR WHIP ERA
...
24  RK  PlAYER  etc...

df <- df[c(-12, -24, -36, -48, -etc), ]
```

This seems inefficient, since my `df` is over a thousand rows long. How can I delete these header rows without having to type out every number from 12 to Timbuktu?

Comment: use the seq function `df[-c(seq(12, nrow(df), by = 12)),]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a sequence with `seq` and use that to remove the rows

```
df[-seq(12, nrow(df), by = 12),]
```

If it is a `data.table` object, the `,` is not needed

```
library(data.table)
df[-seq(12, .N, by = 12)]
```

or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   slice(-seq(12, n(), by = 12))
```

---

Based on the comments from the OP, the intention is to remove duplicate headers in the data read from [here](http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/pitching/_/year/2000/qualified/true/order/false).

Remove the rows where RK column value is 'RK' (specifies the header row)

```
df <- df[df$RK != "RK",]
```

and then change the `type` of the columns

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))
```

Comment: This solution works! Another question: would there be a way to remove rows by the direct text of the column headers?

Comment: @papelr  Thanks, sorry i didn't understand your question.  Could you update your post with a small reproducible example

Comment: You understood the question perfectly - I was just wondering if there was a way to do it by the actual column names in the header. I will add a reproducible sample shortly!

Comment: @papelr  Did you meant you already have a column with sequence numbers i.e. `1:nrow(df)`?  Are we talking about subsetting rows or columns

Comment: No, I didn't until you and MRK posted answers. I understand that there is a numerical way to get rid of the repeated header rows, but I am also curious to see if there is a way to do it by targeting the actual names

Comment: @papelr  If you have a column with values say `c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a')` and you want to get rid of rows with either 'a' or 'c', then `df[!df$col %in% c('a', 'c'),]`

Comment: @papelr If the intention is to remove duplicated rows based on the duplicate elements of a column `df[!duplicated(df$col),]`

Answer (score 3):

An option is to check for `remainder` after dividing by `12`. Exclude rows for which `remainder` is `0`:

```
df[(1:nrow(df) %% 12) !=0,]
```

For `data.table` one can use `.I` as:

```
df[df[,(.I %% 12 != 0)]]
```

**How it works?** Say, your `data.frame` got 36 rows then:

```
(1:36 %% 12) != 0

# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [12] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [23]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [34]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Notice, that `12th`, `24th` and `36th` are `FALSE`. Hence, those rows will be excluded.